# Javascript script to make a stopwatch . having trouble with the reset button. need a second pair of eyes

Tags: javascript

Everything witht he script is working. However the reset button is none functioning. However the reset button is not working. I looked it over for an hour but can find any errors. A second pair of eyes would be great. Thanks guys.

I checked my syntax, and adjusted the quotations within the 00s  when i specified to reset  the variables to 00. No change

```
var seconds = 00;
var tens = 00;
var OutputSeconds = document.getElementById('second');
var OutputTens = document.getElementById('tens');
var buttonStart = document.getElementById('btn-start');
var buttonStop = document.getElementById('btn-stop');
var buttonReset = document.getElementById('btn-reset');
var Interval;
buttonStart.addEventListener('click', () =\>{
clearInterval(Interval);
Interval = setInterval(startTime, 10);
});

    buttonStop.addEventListener('click', () => {
        clearInterval(Interval);
    
    });
    
    buttonReset.addEventListener('click', () => {
        clearInterval(Interval);
        tens = 00;
        seconds = 00;
        OutputSeconds.innerHTML = seconds;
        OutputTens.innerHTML = tens;
    
    
    
    
    });
    
    function startTime(){
        tens++;
        if(tens <= 9){
            OutputTens.innerHTML = "0" + tens;
        }
    
        if(tens > 9 ){
            OutputTens.innerHTML = tens;
    
        }
    
        if(tens > 99){
            seconds++;
            OutputSeconds.innerHTML = "0" + seconds;
            tens = 0; 
            OutputTens.innerHTML = "0" + tens; 
        }
    
        if(seconds > 9) {
            OutputSeconds.innerHTML = seconds;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What exactly does "is not working" mean? Does *anything* happen? Are errors reported? Have you verified that the event handler is being called?

Comment: Ill specify: I have three buttons. A start button, a pause button, and a reset button--- everything is fine- However the reset button is none functional . Nothing happens- no error code

Comment: OK, one more time: have you verified that the event handler is being called when you click on the button?

Comment: ill figure it out myself thanks

Comment: OK, well best of luck. Note that an interval timer running every 10 milliseconds is very fast. You might try slowing that down (just as an experiment) to maybe 100 milliseconds and see if that makes a difference. For what it's worth the code looks pretty much OK to me.

Comment: its fixed. It was a syntax error on line 107